# Rspec tests succeed one by one but not when I run them all together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this code, simplified:

```
describe MyController, type: :controller do

  before(:each) do
    @var1 = FactoryGirl.create(:var1)
    @var2 = FactoryGirl.create(:var2)
    @var3 = FactoryGirl.create(:var3)
  end

  # todo
  describe "#update" do

    # @var1, @var2 and @var3 are being used in each test

    it "should aaa" do
      put :url1, params: { ... } 

      expect(response.status).to eql 200
      r = JSON.parse(response.body)
      expect(r["val1"]).to eql val
    end

    it "should bbb" do
      put :url1, params: { ... } 

      expect(response.status).to eql 200
      r = JSON.parse(response.body)
      expect(r["val1"]).to eql val
    end


    it "should ccc" do
      put :url1, params: { ... } 

      expect(response.status).to eql 200
      r = JSON.parse(response.body)
      expect(r["val1"]).to eql val
    end

  end
end
```

The thing is: **when I run these tests by one one by using line number, they all pass flawlessly.**

When I run them **together**, one the 1st one passes and the other 2 fail: they return 404 for "put"

How can this be? There's nothing deleted or created via "url1", only a single boolean value is being updated.

Comment: Does the :url1 include the object's ID?

Comment: @Rodrigo, no..........

Comment: What seems to be happening is that there's application state that is being preserved across the three tests. What params are you passing in? What happens if you run the three tests in a random order? Which object is being modified by these requests?

Comment: What is `val` in this line `expect(r["val1"]).to eql val`

Comment: Can you post the relevant controller and model tests, so we can better see, if state is being preserved?